# Reactor with Kotlin type inference failed with flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

Trying to convert a `Mono` object that has an iterable inside to a `Flux` I got this error (`kotlinc` console):

```
>>> Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
error: type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter R in fun <R : Any!> flatMapMany(p0: Function<in (Mutable)List<Int!>!, out Publisher<out R!>!>!): Flux<R!>!
Please specify it explicitly.
```

(`Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5))` it's just an example to make it simple)

If I change to the following it works:

```
>>> Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany { Flux.fromIterable(it) }
res28: reactor.core.publisher.Flux<kotlin.Int!>! = MonoFlatMapMany
```

So replacing `flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` by `flatMapMany { Flux.fromIterable(it) }` works, but makes it larger and less functional style, in Java the `Flux::fromIterable` notation does work (`jshell` console example):

```
jshell> Mono.just(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
$6 ==> MonoFlatMapMany
```

I tried to explicitly set the type as required in different ways but nothing works:

- `Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany<Int>(Flux::fromIterable)`
- `Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany(Flux<Int>::fromIterable)`
- `Mono.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5)).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable<Int>)`

Comment: Ya, I am afraid it looks like the type inference is just not capable of making the leap you want at the moment - especially with crossing to java where the generics are less strict than kotlin... they are improving it on every new version I think.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin 1.4 is bringing a more powerful type inference algorithm which might help us with these kinds of issues. But there's nothing we can do about it currently. We just have to write the lambda out explicitly. JetBrains is aware of this usability issue, and is working on it.